# Horizontal galleryview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a horizontal galleyview, first time it loads default images and their size is 200 X 200, after downloading image size can be 200 or less,once image download complets i have called  layoutSubview for resizing continents in scrollview. So  every image download compltes  it sets frames of all imageviews in scrollview, Instead of calling layoutsubview every time is there a another way to handle it....?

Comment: you can try UICollectionView. Refer this tutorial ,http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12